# Why does explicitly subclassing from object in python cause global NameError exceptions?

Tags: python

Some legacy code I'm working with that works [code replaced by problem-reproducing code]:

```
class foo:
    pass

class bar(foo):
    def __new__(cls):
        global BIZ
        if BIZ is not None:
            pass

bar()
```

but when I change it to

```
class foo(object):
```

then python prints:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    bar()
  File "test.py", line 8, in __new__
    if BIZ is not None:
NameError: global name 'BIZ' is not defined
```

Why is this?

Comment: I'm guessing you're not posting your actual code.  It won't say `biz` (lowercase) is undefined if you have `BIZ` (uppercase).  Post your actual code with the actual error.

Comment: If you can't post your code then no one can tell you why it doesn't work.

Comment: @hnasarat -- You don't necessarily need to post the entire code, but if you can come up with a postable (runable) snippet that demonstrates the problem, that would go a long way to getting your problem solved.

Comment: It's because you don't define a global name `BIZ` in your code. `global BIZ` itself doesn't declare a variable; it merely allows you to modify names outside the local scope.

Comment: I've made edits to bring out the OP's question.

Comment: @Wooble -- But that should theoretically fail irrespective of whether foo inherits from `object`, shouldn't it?  -- Hmmm apparently it doesn't ... weird.

Comment: @DSM Thanks! You just beat me to it.

Comment: @Wobble Thanks, too! That helps clear it up a bit. Still it seems that the code isn't being run without subclassing object.

Comment: I'm too lazy to write it up, but it's an old-style class.  `__new__` won't even be called.

Comment: Thanks! Go easy on the downvotes guys. It was an honest question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`__new__` special method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) only applies to [new-style classes](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) (those inheriting directly or indirectly from `object`).  Without subclassing `object` your code isn't getting called.

Comment: So, let me get this straight, you're saying there was no error in the original "legacy" code because the `__new__` method defined in it was never being executed -- correct?

Comment: Thanks. Interesting...given the OP said their legacy code worked, and kind of amazing you [apparently] figured out the problem.

Comment: @martineau Thanks! It's not that amazing; DSM spotted the issue at the same time I did. Just normal debugging skills.

Comment: Agree about DSM also deserving some credit -- but not so much with the latter.